# Not receiving value from CheckBoxPreference in PreferenceScreen?

Tags: java, android

I'm using Eclipse's default "Settings Screen" Activity, which created a class extending PreferenceScreen. The methods being used to grab values seem strange to me, but I'm working with them. I can get the value of an EditTextPreference this way:

```
}else if(preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
                preference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
                int p_value = Integer.valueOf(((EditTextPreference) preference).getText());
                MainActivity.decimals = p_value;
```

This works fine for the EditTextPreference and ListPreference. However, upon trying it with a CheckBoxPreference, like so:

```
}else if(preference instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
                preference = (CheckBoxPreference) preference;
                boolean toastEn = ((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked();
                if(toastEn) {
                    MainActivity.toastsEnabled = true;
                }else MainActivity.toastsEnabled = false;

            }
```

It does not work. From the small amount of debugging I managed to do (Toasts and Logs seem to be very limited in this method), it looks like it's just not getting the value of the CheckBoxPreference.
**Am I going about this correctly?**

Edit: the encapsulating method looks like this (I forgot to add it at first, sorry, it might be important):

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
```

Comment: What does onPreferenceChange return? The purpose of the method is essentially to give the programmer the chance to not accept the new value, buy returning false. You must return true to persist the new value

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html

Comment: The method always returns true after the if/else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add a listener to the checkbox such as [setOnPreferenceChangeListener or setOnPreferenceClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener%28android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener%29)

Comment: I don't believe that's possible with the structure of the activity. I'm calling instances of Preference in it's OnPreferenceChangeListener, not referencing specific elements - hence why I thought it was weird.

Answer (score 0):

That is really strange Preferences code.

What I did for Preferences was the following:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  }
}
```

Where the res\xml\preferences.xml looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="MusicEnabled"
    android:title="@string/musicenabled"
/>
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="SoundEnabled"
    android:title="@string/soundenabled"
/>
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="IntroEnabled"
    android:title="@string/introsoundenabled"
/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And you get its values with the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
soundEnabled = sp.getBoolean("SoundEnabled", false);
```